Name of a book that has to do with a vampire family?
I read this book back in the early 2000s in either elementary school or middle school or high school. It was a chapter book and I believe the front is a vampire family standing in front of their Victorian house with their son and their fangs out. I thought it was Living With Vampires by Jeremy Strong but it's not because this book had more chapters.
I remember they live in a neighborhood either people think they are weird or suspect that they are vampires. I think I remember a part where they invite people over and I think they suck their blood. And I think the son is trying to protect his family.

Could be Ma and Pa Dracula by Ann Martin

Convinced he leads a normal life, sleeping during the day and waking at night to do lessons and play while his parents work at the blood bank, nine-year-old Jonathan is astounded when he accidentally discovers how other people live


